# waitForCondition method never returning?

Tags: intern

I'm trying to use Intern to author a first functional test, and I can't get around the following problem: when running the following test script

```
define(["intern!object",
    "intern/chai!assert"
], function(registerSuite, assert){

    registerSuite({
        name: "suite",
        "test": function(){
            var browser = this.remote;
            console.log("HELLO !");
            browser.get("http://www.google.com", function() {
                console.log("PAGE LOADED !");
                browser.waitForCondition("!!window.document.gbqf", 1000, function(err, value){
                    console.log("LET'S BEGIN... ");
                    browser.eval("window.document.gbqf", function(err, value){
                        console.log("BYE BYE !");
                        browser.quit();
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

in chrome, using selenium server standalone 2.32.0 and chromedriver 26.0.1383.0 for windows, my test never end and the last message displayed in the console is "PAGE LOADED !".

Does anyone has an idea of how I'm suppose to write this test, or have a link to some proper (real life) functional tests examples ?

Thanks for your help,

Sebastien

Comment: Seems that this syntax is not supported: this.browser is a Promise, and the return this.browser.get(...).doSomething(...).doSomethingElse(...) syntax must be used. As a consequence, unfortunately, it is not possible to debug a test by setting break points in the test code.

Answer (score 0):

The functional interface does not use callback arguments, it uses promises instead. Your code should look like this:

```js
define([
    "intern!object",
    "intern/chai!assert"
], function (registerSuite, assert) {
    registerSuite({
        name: "suite",
        "test": function () {
            var browser = this.remote;
            console.log("HELLO !");
            return browser
                .get("http://www.google.com")
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("PAGE LOADED !");
                })
                .waitForCondition("!!window.document.gbqf", 1000)
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("LET'S BEGIN... ");
                })
                .eval("window.document.gbqf")
                .then(function (value) {
                    console.log("BYE BYE !");
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Note in particular:

1. The last promise chain from `this.remote` is returned by the test function to indicate to Intern that the test is asynchronous
2. `waitForCondition` does not return a value
3. You should never call `quit` yourself; this is handled by Intern once the test is complete